# Compress GeoJSON by aliasing

Tags: geojson, d3

I just come to know the GeoJSON files. I need to load the files as fast as possible to reduce render time in browser. So I want to reduce the file sizes by aliasing for example turning 'geometry' to 'g', 'Point' to 'p' and so on (I found the keywords are really redundant) while I still want to make use of the d3-geo functions to operate on it. Is it possible?

PS: My data is not suitable for converting to TopoJSON since they are merely separated points and line-segments.

Comment: Why not ZIP them, load them and then unZIP them?

Comment: obfuscating code can also do this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454502/does-obfuscation-affect-performance